# Angular2: Unhandled Promise rejection: No provider for @Injectable

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an `AppModule` which imports `CoreModule`. The purpouse of `CoreModule` is to handle with data access services, so `CoreModule` provides `UserService`, `PlansService` and so on:

```
@NgModule({
  providers: [
    UsersService,
    PlansService,
    {
      provide: LocationStrategy,
      useClass: ('production' === ENV ? HashLocationStrategy : PathLocationStrategy)
    }
  ]
})
export class CoreModule { }
```

So on `AppModule` I import it:

```
@NgModule({
  bootstrap: [ App ],
  declarations: [
    App,
    ErrorComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    CoreModule,   <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTES, { useHash: true })
  ]
})
export class AppModule {
```

Nevertheless, on `LoginComponent` angular is telling me it's not able to get a provider for `UserService`:

```
@Component({
    ...
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private commty: UsersService)
```

`LoginModule` is loaded lazyly according to its router configuration and it's:

```
export const routes = [
  { path: '', component: LoginComponent, pathMatch: 'full' }
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    LoginComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    AlertModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes),
  ],
})
export default class LoginModule {
  static routes = routes;
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Do I need to `import` `CoreModule` innto LoginModule? If I do it, what about `CoreModule` instances? Is it loaded twice?

This the error I'm getting from angular:

> Unhandled Promise rejection: No provider for UsersService!

Comment: Yes, you have to import CoreModule into LoginModule, because there is no any relation between. It should be only one instance but you can test it.

Comment: Thanks @Igor. It keeps failing yet. The message is the same.

Comment: Do you have @Injectable() annotation on your XxxService classes?

Comment: Yes, `@Injectable() export class PlansService {...}`

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to import CoreModule into LoginModule. You can just solve the problem by setting UsersService as a provider of LoginComponent.

**LoginComponent:**

```
@Component({
    providers: [ UsersService  ]
    //...
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private commty: UsersService)
}
```

Comment: If I use this apporach, `UserService` is going to be instanciated several times, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

because you're using lazy load, you need import CoreModule in both lazy and non-lazy module.

> Now that we have proven that lazy loaded modules create their own
>   branch on the Dependency Injection tree, we need to learn how to deal
>   with services that are imported by means of a shared module in both an
>   eager and lazy loaded module.

https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/modules/shared-modules-di.html

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    LoginComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    AlertModule,
    CoreModule, // <- here
    RouterModule.forChild(routes),
  ],
})
export default class LoginModule {
  static routes = routes;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. According to the documentation link you have written, thiswould be the way. Nevertheless, it keeps failing!!? It's really strange! The message is the same...

Comment: oh, i'm using this way to implement lazy loading too. btw, did you naming your service `UsersService` or just `UserService`

Comment: `UsersService`, why?

Comment: > so CoreModule provides UserService

Comment: Mmm... what about `exports` in `CoreModule`?

Comment: `exports` will exports component, directive, module, pipe, ... you don't need export service. btw, just try ;-)